# Problem with dategrop by period in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue with report. My user want to see something like this:

[image: All days in time period grouped by year, month, week]

I created a simple CTE query:

```
Declare
    @date_value datetime = dateadd(year,-3,getdate()),
    @endtime datetime = getdate(),
    @interval int = 1; 

With cte(stime) as
(
    select
        @date_value
    union all
    select
        dateadd(day, @interval, stime)
    from cte
    where dateadd(day, @interval, stime) < @endtime 
)
select stime
from cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

But if I start grouping by year for example can't produce groups and details like on picture above.

Any help will be useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't even try to replicate the format in your Query's resultset. That's a Pivot Table in Excel, and if you want the data to look like that at the end, then that should be done in the presentation layer. SQL is completely the wrong place for trying to do this.

Comment: So it's better to get days and leave grouping to SSRS and PowerBI?

Comment: For what you have here, yes, add the groups in your presentation layer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll take grouping to app level.